# Add (multiple) values to a data frame with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using R shiny in combination with ggplot to visualize a certain dataset. I want the user to be able to add values to this dataset. I can get my application so far as to show me the original data + one data point, but as soon as the user enters a new point, the old one is gone: the user-input data is not actually stored in my dataframe.

Some of the code I'm using (changed variable names for simplicity):

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {     
    output$newPlot <- renderPlot({   
      input$addButton
      isolate({
        x <- as.numeric(input$x)
        y <- as.numeric(input$y)
        if (!is.na(y)) {
          data <- rbind(data, data.frame(x = x, y = y))

          # more code here

        }

        # more code here 

        plot <- myPlot(data)
        print(plot)

      })
    })
  }
)
```

The user can give values for x and y with `textInput` and then submit those values with a button (`actionButton`). Each time the user hits 'add', the most recently inputted values for x and y are shown on top of the original data, but any other values the user inputted (in the same session) are lost. How do I get shiny to remember my users inputs and plot all of it?

Comment: Do you want the new inputs permanently stored (i.e. still there if you restart the shiny app?) or just for the session?

Comment: Just for the session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce yours specifically given the code you provided but perhaps an example will help you.  The part you need is `reactiveValues`, this allows you to store your dataset and update it throughout the session as you see fit.  Perhaps this can help you fix your problem?

```
require(shiny)
data(iris)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      headerPanel('Adding Data'),
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("species", label="Add a new species", value="Enter species"),
        numericInput("sepal.length", label="Add a new sepal length", value=""),
        numericInput("sepal.width", label="Add a new speal width", value=""),
        numericInput("petal.length", label="Add a new petal length", value=""),
        numericInput("petal.width", label="Add a new petal width", value=""),
        actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table"))
    ),

    server = function(input, output) {     
      # just a small part of iris for display
      iris_sample <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 10),]
      row.names(iris_sample) <- NULL

      # The important part of reactiveValues()
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$df <- iris_sample
      observe({

        # your action button condition
        if(input$addButton > 0) {
          # create the new line to be added from your inputs
          newLine <- isolate(c(input$sepal.length, input$sepal.width, input$petal.length, input$petal.width, input$species))
          # update your data
          # note the unlist of newLine, this prevents a bothersome warning message that the rbind will return regarding rownames because of using isolate.
          isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
        }
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, this indeed helped me to get the effect I wanted.

Comment: This is very helpful for me too. However, i could not manage some issues which i indicate in this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930846/another-follow-up-to-add-values-to-a-reactive-table-in-shiny-when-we-already-h

if you would help me, i ll so glad.

Comment: `addData <- observe({...` with `observe` you cannot assign a value to a variable.

Comment: @Stophface thanks for pointing that out.  I have fixed it now.  It worked fine in this case but you are correct that nothing is assigned and it shouldn't be there.